# How to display correct years from 1920 to current year in datepicker drop down for year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using a jquery datepicker UI plugin below:

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#dobDate" ).datepicker({minDate: new Date(1920, 1 - 1, 01), maxDate:0, 
                        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "Images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
        });
});
```

The url for this plugin is [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year)

Now the problem I am having is that I want to display the months and year drop down menus. Now it does this but I want it to display the years from 1920 to current year. At moment what it is doing is only display it from 2002 to current year. I have to click on the arrows to go onto a month before the year 2002 to then be able to see years 1992 to 2002 in the drop down menu for year.

So my question is how can I display years 1920 to current year in the year drop down menu?

Comment: u want to set 1920 as the selected year on click of datepicker??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `'c'` for the current year like:

```
$('#dobDate').datepicker({yearRange : '1920:c',changeYear: true});
```

use also the `changeYear: true`

working demo [Fiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/h8VWW/)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`yearRange`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) option

Use it like this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({yearRange : '1920:2012'});
```

Comment: As you answered first, you will get the best answer

Comment: Ha ha, and still you accept the other answer. It was better. I upvoted for it too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "yearRange", "1920:c" );
```

`c` stands for current year. The default is `c-10:c+10`

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange